# Cron job error on filetime

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I have a php script which runs fine direct from a web page that checks the last modified time of all html files for a site map, However when i run it as a cron job if errors out.

Below is the script, the cron job and the error.

```
$path = "/home/mydir/"; 

// Open the folder 
$dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Unable to open $path"); 

// Loop through the files 
while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) { 
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "index.php" ) 

        continue; 
        if(strpos($file, ".html") !== false) {
        $a=filemtime($file);
        }
    }
}
```

php /home/mydir/pdate.php /dev/null && echo "Site Map completed "$(date) >>/var/log/cron.log

Error
PHP Warning:  filemtime(): stat failed

Any ideas on what i should change for this one please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in another directory.
Either:

```
chdir($path);
```

Or:

```
filemtime($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file);
```

Comment: Many thanks. Solved with the solution "filemtime($path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file)"